# Mapping to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and using Fermat to determine irreducibility of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm working through an exercise in Pinter's algebra book about different ways to determine irreducibility of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.

> It asks to show that $x^5+1$ is irreducible by sending it to $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ and showing it is irreducible there.

Namely, if $h : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ is the natural homomorphism, let $\bar{h} : \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ be the homomorphism defined by $\bar{h}(a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n) = h(a_0) + h(a_1)x + \cdots + h(a_n)x^n$. I showed that if $\bar{h}(a(x))$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ and $a(x)$ is monic, then $a(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I know how to use this for polynomials like $x^4-10x^2+1$ (just send it to $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, and a previous exercise showed that $x^4+1$ is irreducible there), but I'm puzzled about how this technique helps with $x^5+1$, which doesn't have a term that would disappear under some mapping.  I keep thinking there must be some use of Fermat's little theorem here, and am tempted to send $x^5+1$ to $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]$. Over $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]$, I know that $x^5+1$, viewed as a polynomial function, is equivalent to $x+1$ (which is irreducible). But I don't think this implies that $x^5+1$ is irreducible because as formal polynomial expressions $x^5+1$ and $x+1$ are different (i.e. coefficients of $x^k$ do not match).

Any tips?

Comment: $f(-1)=0$, so this is reducible over any field (and in particular over $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: Ah, thanks... But suppose that we were looking at $x^6+1$-- could you show this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by sending it to $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x]$?

Comment: Again, no luck: $\pm i$ are zeros, so $x^2+1$ is a divisor.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would attack this by observing that the roots of $x^n+1$ are $2n$th roots of unity, and then we know that the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible, which should clarify matters.